# looking for a callback to know when databinding is done

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am experiencing a problem when i use view model together with databinding in Android development, i need to capture the screen after databinding is finished in view which should completes draw all the data from viewmodel after viewmodel asychronously fetch the image from the network.

Is there any api available for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will give you what you want because it will call you when the binding completes. You will have to wait for the draw after:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#addOnRebindCallback(android.databinding.OnRebindCallback)

You'll have to wait until after the onDraw() call after the binding completes, but you can get that call here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html

Still not positive that's enough, but if you post your Runnable in the onDraw() call, you should be able to capture the screen shot.